# Vector comparison

Tags: c++

Vector function emplace()
 My emplace function does not work. Any help would be appreciated

```
vector <int> vec1;
vector <int> vec2(4,0);
vector <int>::iterator iter1;
vector <int>::iterator iter2;

srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
n =rand()%10+1;
vec1.push_back(n);
}

for(iter1=vec1.begin();iter1<vec1.end();iter1++){

 for(iter2=vec2.begin();iter2<vec2.end();iter2++){

   if(*iter1<=*iter2){
  //vec2.emplace(iter1,*iter1);
  //print();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your _if condition_ won't enter unless the value in vector1 is 0. Even in that case, it's not really doing what you want. Are you sure the issue is with emplace and not with the if? Can you explain what you mean when you say that your "emplace function does not work"?

As an aside, you might want to reconsider how to sort vector2, there are a number of better algorithms out there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Answer (score 2):

```
for(iter2=vec2.begin();iter2<vec2.end();iter2++){
```

Because vec2 starts populated with four values of 0, you will never find an element where *iter1 <= *iter2 unless *iter1 == 0.

Instead of zero-initializing it to avoid allocations, you want to `reserve` space.

```
vec2.reserve(vec1.size());
```

and then instead of a for loop you can use `std::lower_bound` to find the insert location:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void print_vec(const char* label, const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    std::cout << label << ": ";
    for (int v : vec) {
        std::cout << v << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector <int> vec1 { 4, 1, 2, 2, 5 };
    std::vector <int> vec2;

    print_vec("v1", vec1);

    vec2.reserve(vec1.size());

    for (int v : vec1) {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), v);
        if (it == vec2.end() || *it != v)
            vec2.emplace(it, v);
        print_vec("v2", vec2);
    }

    print_vec("Fin", vec2);


    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/o5td9K

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is like insertion sort. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
has the pseudo-code. At each step you will check every element in vector 2 and place the new element where it belongs (while loop).